# Multidimensional function smooth (in ${C_c}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, exponential-function

> Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  with $\phi(x):=\exp(1/(|x|^2-1))$ for $|x|<1$ and $\phi(x):=0$ otherwise and $\phi_{\varepsilon}(x)=1/\varepsilon^n\cdot\phi(x/\varepsilon)$. Show that $\phi_\varepsilon$ is in ${C_c}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I know how to show it if $n=1$, but how can I show it for a multidimensional function? (Maybe induction?) I would be glad if you gave me some tips.

Comment: Write $\phi$ as a composition, $\phi = \psi \circ N$, where $N(x) = \lvert x\rvert$, and $\psi$ is the one-dimensional version to treat $x\neq 0$. Near $0$, use that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert^2-1}$ is smooth, and $\exp$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What should I do if $|x|=1$?

Comment: Since $x \mapsto \lvert x\rvert$ is $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$, the smoothness of $\phi$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ follows from the smoothness of $\psi$ on $\mathbb{R}$. You wrote that you know how to show that.